# Find named mutexes in an C# application

Tags: c#, mutex, thread-synchronization

How do I find the named mutexes in an running C# application, provided I do not have the source code of that application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Process Explorer utility from SysInternals can list the handles in use by a process; some of those handles might be named mutexes, which you can then examine.