# C# a way to get number of named mutexes in system

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, mutex

Is in C#/.NET Core any way to get names or just number of named mutexes in windows? Especially the mutexes, which were created by my application (there could be a few instances).

I found post [Find named mutexes in an C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596681/find-named-mutexes-in-an-c-sharp-application) but the solution is an external tool. I need to receive it in code of my application

UPDATE:
Actually I needed it to have some kind of counter of created systemwide mutexes in multiple instances of my dll/application. I solved the problem with usage of Semahore - WaitOne and Release methods to manipulate and get the current count.
Thanks for your time and ideas

Comment: With mutexes the assumption is that you will know the name, to enumerate them you would need things like the undocumented NtQuerySystemInformation & friends.  Perhaps you should explain why you need to do this, there are better ways to share data across process boundaries.

Comment: no problem take all mutant handles and names in your process, but for what ?

Comment: You could use WMI class [`Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Objects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa394315(v=vs.85)) to monitor objects contained by the operating system such as events, **mutexes**, processes, sections, semaphores, and threads. The Properties `Mutexes` is the count of the number of mutexes in the computer at the time of data collection.